# how do I composition a screen using mir?

Tags: xrandr, mir

I am using ubuntu touch and would like to know how to warp (composition) a screen. In particular, I need to stretch it and flip it (horizontally) to project onto a curved surface correctly. If this was X11, I could use xrandr, but I dont know if the same things are possible using Mir.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Touch uses Lomiri, which replaces the default Mir compositor with a Qt based one. You'll need to make code changes to Lomiri to support this usecase.